# Closed form expression for this infinite series?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

Is there a closed-form expression for this series?

$\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq 1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot[1-(1-x)^k]\cdot \frac{1}{k}$

Any answers, ideas or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No closed form expression in terms of elementary functions, but if you are satisfied with special functions (incomplete Gamma function $\Gamma$ and exponential integral Ei), then
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot[1-(1-x)^k]\cdot \frac{1}{k}=$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\,\Re \bigg(\text{Ei}\left(\lambda\right)+\ln (x-1)+\Gamma \left[0,\lambda (x-1)\right]\biggr),\;\;\lambda,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
($\Re$ indicates the real part.) Here is a plot of the $x$-dependence for $\lambda=+1$ (blue) and $\lambda=-1$ (gold).

[image]

Comment: Is "No closed form expression in terms of elementary functions" a theorem, or a conjectural observation?

Comment: well, this would imply that $\Gamma(0,x)$ is an elementary function, which it is not.

Comment: You might want to put a carriage return after the equal sign to force all of the RHS to be on one line. And does "It's this expression for  any real λ or x" mean "It's this expression if λ is real or x is real" rather than  "It's this expression if λ is real and x is real"?